# Custom toolbar with CKEditor in rails with ckeditor-rails

Tags: jquery, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I am using ckeditor-rails gem to integrate CKEditor with rails. I also use http://ckeditor.com/builder to generate the toolbar, however I want to customize a bit more by removing some. This is the config from the builder

```js
/**
 * @license Copyright (c) 2003-2016, CKSource - Frederico Knabben. All rights reserved.
 * For licensing, see LICENSE.md or http://ckeditor.com/license
 */

CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
 
 // %REMOVE_START%
 // The configuration options below are needed when running CKEditor from source files.
 config.plugins = 'dialogui,dialog,about,a11yhelp,basicstyles,blockquote,clipboard,panel,floatpanel,menu,contextmenu,resize,button,toolbar,elementspath,enterkey,entities,popup,filebrowser,floatingspace,listblock,richcombo,format,horizontalrule,htmlwriter,wysiwygarea,image,indent,indentlist,fakeobjects,link,list,magicline,maximize,pastetext,pastefromword,removeformat,showborders,sourcearea,specialchar,menubutton,scayt,stylescombo,tab,table,tabletools,undo,wsc';
 config.skin = 'moono';
 // %REMOVE_END%

 // Define changes to default configuration here.
 // For complete reference see:
 // http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config

 // The toolbar groups arrangement, optimized for two toolbar rows.
 config.toolbarGroups = [
  { name: 'clipboard',   groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
  { name: 'editing',     groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ] },
  { name: 'links' },
  { name: 'insert' },
  { name: 'forms' },
  { name: 'tools' },
  { name: 'document',    groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
  { name: 'others' },
  '/',
  { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
  { name: 'paragraph',   groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ] },
  { name: 'styles' },
  { name: 'colors' },
  { name: 'about' }
 ];

 // Remove some buttons provided by the standard plugins, which are
 // not needed in the Standard(s) toolbar.
 config.removeButtons = 'Underline,Subscript,Superscript';

 // Set the most common block elements.
 config.format_tags = 'p;h1;h2;h3;pre';

 // Simplify the dialog windows.
 config.removeDialogTabs = 'image:advanced;link:advanced';
};
```

From the code above I learn that buttons on the toolbars can be removed by

```js
config.removeButtons = 'Underline,Subscript,Superscript';
```

Now I want to remove the image, insert horizontal line and insert special character from the tool bar.

```js
    config.removeButtons = 'Underline,Subscript,Superscript,Image,Insert Horizontal Line, Insert Special Character';
```

It works for Image button but not for the other 2 buttons.

where can I get the values that represent the buttond to remove (in my case the **horizontal line** and the **special character** buttons ? I think it must be mentioned somewhere in CKEditor website that I just could not find.

Your help will be highly appreciated.

ps: the ckeditor-rails uses jquery ckeditor internally.

Comment: I found the list of toolbar items from http://www.onehippo.org/library/concepts/document-types/html-fields/ckeditor-toolbar-items.html.  there are 6 columns and the first column called "Toolbar item" contains the values I am looking for. however @Anna Tomanek has good reason and the builder is good enough to customize the tool. I just did not know how to use it well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use CKBuilder to generate your CKEditor build, it makes more sense to remove the plugins that provide the buttons you are not going to use - otherwise you will still be loading these plugins for no good reasons at all which makes little sense performance-wise. See also [4 Common CKEditor Installation Mistakes And How To Avoid Them](http://ckeditor.com/blog/4-Common-CKEditor-Installation-Mistakes-And-How-To-Avoid-Them).

If for some reason you still insist on just removing the buttons in your configuration, check the [Toolbar Configurator](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_toolbar). It's a tool that is designed to help you adjust the toolbar for your specific editor package - you can find it in the `samples/index.html` file. It will let you easily find the names of the buttons ("Advanced" version) or even better, adjust the toolbar live by selecting the available buttons ("Basic" version).